# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de tratar/evitar sql TimeOut error?

Tags: c#, sql

Estaba desarrollando una aplicacion en la que lanzo consultas de forma automática, consecutivamente, siempre las mismas.

El problema viene cuando la BBDD tarda en responder, de alguna forma, sin saber por que, tal vez por el tráfico o por la cantidad de información, la consulta tarda más de lo debido, provocando el **TimeOut Error**

El mensaje que me sale es

> **MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:**
>    'Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.'

Las consultas las guardo en un `List<String>` para no lanzarlas todas de golpe usando Union y no sobrecargar la BBDD.

```
for(int i = 0; i<consultas.Count;i++){
   consulta.CommandText = querys[i];
   dr = consulta.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Tratar la excepción no me soluciona el problema, ya que **los datos no pueden faltar**.

**¿Hay alguna forma de evitar el TimeOut?**

Comment: Depende de lo que pretendas y a qué está enfocada tu aplicación. Lo más recomendable es agilizar las consultas, hacer consultas más pequeñas. Si no puedes hacer eso, sube el timeout del servidor de DB que uses,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya que no puedo agilizar el tiempo de las consultas ya que son cosas muy simples de

```
select count(*)
where esto = esto
and esto = esto
group by esto
```

Lo que he acabdo haciendo es un `consulta.CommandTimeout = 900;` aplicado sobre el `MySqlCommand consulta`

(Desconocía la propiedad de CommandTimeout)

Comment: ¿Tienes índices definidos en tus tablas? ¿Estás buscando por campos que son clave/índice?

Comment: No tengo índices, sobre esas tablas tengo permiso de solo lectura, no puedo hacer nada.

Comment: ¿Cómo de grandes son las tablas? Como indicas, es una consulta simple y, a no ser que la tabla sea enorme, no parece que debiera dar un timeout.